# adobe illustrator reflect one handler

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I only have 1 handler on the point. Is there a way to add the other one symmetrically ?

Answer (score 1):

With the **Pen Tool**, hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down and and click-drag the anchor. 
This will convert the anchor to a smooth point.

Or, use the **Convert Anchor Point Tool** (which is under the Pen tool) to merely click-drag on the anchor.